# "flutter doctor" stucked, none of the flutter command working

Tags: flutter, dart

I am running flutter on my windows machine, it was working earlier and I have created demo project with it.

Today when I run VSCode it asked me to update flutter and I did, but when it is updated it is not able to run any command. It doesn't do anything, neither error nor success. It just get stucked with any flutter command.

[image]

[image]

**Note : It was working earlier, so there is no chance of setting environment variables, still I have double checked it and it is there.**

Comment: You can check this, If in your case https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/35185

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find any solution for this so the last available approach for me was to reinstall flutter SDK and it worked.

**Note:** If you are windows user, you might get an error about `PowerShell` version, you must have `PowerShell` version greater than 5.1